# "The command 'pything gl3w_gen.py' exited with code 2."

Tags: python

I'm trying to rebuild https://github.com/crosire/reshade and I'm getting an error in visual studio. I've been trying to look online for a while for a solution but none has come up, especially when I don't even know what error code 2 even is, since I cant find any documentation on it.

Additionally, I've installed python on my computer, and as a safety measure, I've even tried to install python to the project with the NuGet manager. Nothing works. What's the issue?

Comment: What is the error your getting in VS?

Comment: "The command 'pything gl3w_gen.py' exited with code 2." in gl3w.vcxproj on line 91

Comment: That is most likely _File not found_. Try specifying the full path to _python(3).exe_ (make sure to enclose it in _dblquotes_ (`"`), if it contains spaces). Same thing for _gl3w\_gen.py_.

Comment: Where would I go to include that?